# Bold a portion of a Label's `Caption` property in VBA (Microsoft Access)

Tags: vba, label

How do I bold a certain word in the caption of a Microsoft Access label?

If it helps, the text itself is stored in a Microsoft Access table.

An example is below. I have a Microsoft Access form with a label, in the `Form_Load()` event I set the caption property of this label to the value returned in a DLookup query like so:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.Label0.Caption = DLookup("Field1", "Table1", "[ID] = 1")

End Sub
```

My text is as follows:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I want to embolden the word **Lazy**. Is this possible? If so, how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: From what I know and have researched, it doesn't seem possible.  A work-around would be to create 3 separate labels, and put the words you would like to be bold into a label that is set to bold.

Comment: Yeah that is the approach I went with in the end, it felt wrong though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not mention the version of Access, for 2007 (AFAIK) and 2010, you can create a textbox and set the Text Format on the data tab to Rich Text. You can then set the Control Source to:

```
="The quick <b>brown</b> fox"
```

Change a few more properties, such as Locked and Enabled and you will have a textbox that looks and acts like a label.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's way better than a Web Control. :)  I didn't think of looking on the Data properties tab - what an odd place to put Text Format.  Good one, though.

Comment: @DickKusleika Thanks, pity about the version dependency, for earlier versions, I guess your idea would be the better bet.

Comment: Apologies, I am using 2007. And thankyou, this worked a treat!

Answer (score 3):

How bad do you want this?  Because I have a really crazy answer, but it might work.

Replace your label with a Web Browser Control, create a temporary html file, then point the Web Browser to that.  You'll need to add a field to the underlying table (or at least I did) because the control has to be bound or you can't change the ControlSource - I think.

I put a Web Browser control on a form, turned scrollbars off, and generally tried to make it look like a label.  I didn't have complete success with that, but maybe you're better at it than me.

I added a Text field to my table called "FakeLabel".  The Web Browser control source should point to that field.

For purposes of testing, I put a commandbutton on the form with this code

```
Private Sub Command113_Click()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim lFile As String

    sFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\fakelabel.html"
    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sFile For Output As lFile

    Write #lFile, "The <strong>quick</strong> brown fox jumped over the <em>lazy</em> dog"

    Close lFile

    Me.Recordset.Edit
    Me.Recordset.Fields("FakeLabel").Value = sFile
    Me.Recordset.Update

    Me.WebBrowser112.Requery

End Sub
```

Here's what it looks like after I click the button.  If you can get rid of that top padding, it could really look like a label.

[image: access form with web control serving as label]

Comment: +1 for the creativity, I went with Remou's answer but I will certainly keep this in mind, I'm sure it will come in handy at some point! Thankyou

Comment: +1, I now use this to keep a simple changelog ('What's New?') for my databases. A button on the main form opens a small popup window containing a Web Browser control pointing to changelog.html, stored on the server. It's much easier to update and format the changelog than it ever was using labels.