# Partial Textbox Formatting in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, textbox, formatting, report

I have a report which draws info from the DB to fill in a "Legend" of sorts; I'm wondering if there is a way to partially format the info in the text box? Something like

```
=Formatting([Title], "green 10pt") & ": " & Formatting([Description], "blue 7pt")
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there are any functions like this in Access for reports. I know I could put a second textbox for "Description" and change its formatting, but there's a few reasons why I can't do that.

If there's a simple way, great, if not that's fine too; I just havn't been able to find any documents saying "No, impossible" or "Yes, possible".

Comment: If you are using MS Access 2007 --> you can set a control to Rich Text, otherwise, no.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903894/bold-a-portion-of-a-labels-caption-property-in-vba-microsoft-access/11908410#11908410

Comment: The standard textbox does not allow this functionality, but the Microsoft RichTextBox control does, although I don't ever use it.

Comment: Are there drawbacks to RichTextBox? (Using 2010)

Comment: Access 2010 you are not using an external ActiveX, so you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies; I guess I wasn't wording my google searches properly as it seems from the link that this has (basically) been asked before. If anybody wants to throw down a detailed answer for others (maybe a link to the formats), easy rep, and helps other bad-googlers.

Comment: I have already answered this question previously in [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903894/bold-a-portion-of-a-labels-caption-property-in-vba-microsoft-access/11908410#11908410), to all intents, this is a duplicate. I posted a link to the original above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning how to do this myself, but I've played with a few codes.  In Report Design, change the 'Text Format' of the control to 'Rich Text'.  Then you can type in your string.  For example: '="The ***fox*** ran away from the hunter."  The word 'fox' will be bold, italic, and underlined.  I'm looking at other codes, and have played with a few, but this will get you started.  Before the word is the start of the change..., and after the word marks the end of the change.  This is the syntax for MS Access.

In the above, it shows the result.  The syntax `<b><i><u>fox</b></i></u>`